# Inheriting interface properties without static properties in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, I'd like to use a pattern that looks something like this:

[image: Two pairs of an interface & static helper, where the interfaces have an inheritance relation but the static helpers don't]

All `FooBar<T>` are also of type `Bar<T>`, and I want to express this in the type system. However, I'd also like to be able to write static methods like `Bar.create<T>(...)` and `FooBar.create<T>(...)`, with no relationship between those functions. Adding a property to the `Bar<T>` type should force all `FooBar<T>` to also include that property, but adding a method to the static `Bar` should *not* force that method to appear in `FooBar`.

In C#, I'd simply have `interface IBar<T>` and `static class Bar`, but in keeping with TypeScript's naming convention I'd prefer the names as shown, unless there is no other option.

Here was my first attempt, which resulted in the error "All declarations of 'Bar' must have identical type parameters":

```js
interface Bar<T> {
    readonly x: T;
}

class Bar {
    static create<T>(x: T) : Bar<T> {
        return { x: x };
    }
}
```

Classes would also be acceptable here, so my second attempt was this:

```js
class Bar<T> {
    static create<T>(x: T) {
        return new Bar(x);
    }

    static barOnly() { }

    constructor(public readonly x: T) { }
}

class FooBar<T> extends Bar<T> {
    static create<T>(x: T, y: T) {
        return new FooBar<T>(x, y);
    }

    constructor(x: T, public readonly y: T) {
        super(x);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it looks like `FooBar` attempts to inherit even the static members of `Bar`, so not only do I end up with the undesirable `FooBar.barOnly`, but it doesn't even compile since "Class static side of 'typeof FooBar' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof Bar'" because the types of `create` are incompatible.

**Is there any way to have the "interface-side" inherited, without the "static-side"?** I suspect there must be, because TS seems very good at being able to capture all the odd things people do in JavaScript, and I can get what I want in raw JavaScript. The following code has all the properties I want, except, of course, the strong typing from TypeScript:

```js
function Bar(x) {
    this.x = x;
}

Bar.create = x => new Bar(x);

Bar.prototype.getX = function () {
    return this.x;
}

function FooBar(x, y) {
    Bar.call(this, x);
    this.y = y;
}

FooBar.create = (x, y) => new FooBar(x, y);

FooBar.prototype = Object.create(Bar.prototype);

FooBar.prototype.getY = function () {
    return this.y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a type assertion in the `extends` clause of the derived class to essentially erase the static part of the type.

Not sure if this will not cause other problems, but it appears to work:

```
class Bar<T> {
  static create<T>(x: T) {
    console.log("Bar");
    return new Bar(x);
  }

  static barOnly() { }

  constructor(public readonly x: T) { }
}

class FooBar<T> extends (Bar as new <T>(x: T) => Bar<T>)<T> {
  static create<T>(x: T, y: T) {
    return new FooBar<T>(x, y);
  }

  constructor(x: T, public readonly y: T) {
    super(x);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Titian's answer for making this work with classes, I was able to accomplish this purely with interfaces by making the "static" helpers into their own object with the same name as the interface:

```
interface Bar<T> {
    readonly x: T;
}

const Bar = {
    create: function <T>(x: T): Bar<T> {
        return { x: x };
    },
    barOnly: () => { }
};

interface FooBar<T> extends Bar<T> {
    readonly y: T;
}

const FooBar = {
    create: function <T>(x: T, y: T): FooBar<T> {
        return { x: x, y: y };
    }
}
```